# Knowing if app is moving to background in WillResignActive?

Tags: ios, background

Is there away to know if WillResignActive is due to moving app to the background or due to opening Control / Message Center ?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you asking if we know whether the app resigned active because it entered the background or if the Control Center was opened?

Answer (score 0):

If your app has moved to background then the `DidEnterBackground` message will also be sent. You can potentially check after a small delay after `WillResignActive` to see if both messages were sent.

**EDIT: Check this code**

```
@interface HSAppDelegate ()
{
    BOOL _enteredBackground;
}

@end

@implementation HSAppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    _enteredBackground = NO;
    _window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    _window.rootViewController = [HSViewController new];
    [_window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (!_enteredBackground)
        {
            // Do whatever you want here.
        }
        else
        {
            // This won't get called until the app comes back to foreground.
        }
    });
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    _enteredBackground = YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    _enteredBackground = NO;
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks. The point is that I need to do the action in WillResignActive and I can not wait for DidEnterBackground.

Comment: I've added example code for you. Hopefully it can help point you in the right direction. The reason that it works is that calling `dispatch_async` on the same queue forces the block to be called not the next run loop.